# auto script to open a modal and click on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
document.querySelector("#profile > article.player-stats.protected > footer > .button:nth-child(13)").click()
```

is there a way to Automatically "click" on on modal pop up  `css=.success`

Comment: Can you be more clear and expressive about your question and requirements?

Comment: im trying to click an X-path with CSS, button opens a hidden modal

Comment: This is my target that opens the modal i need to click          [  "target": "linkText=Buy",
      "targets": [
        ["linkText=Buy", "linkText"],
        ["css=footer:nth-child(3) > .green", "css:finder"],
        ["xpath=//a[contains(text(),'Buy')]", "xpath:link"],
        ["xpath=//section[@id='profile']/article/footer/a", "xpath:idRelative"],
        ["xpath=(//a[contains(@href, '#')])[9]", "xpath:href"],
        ["xpath=//footer/a", "xpath:position"],
        ["xpath=//a[contains(.,'Buy')]", "xpath:innerText"]

Comment: Modal  "targets": [
        ["linkText=Buy", "linkText"],
        ["name=action", "name"],
        ["css=.success", "css:finder"],
        ["xpath=(//a[contains(text(),'Buy')])[11]", "xpath:link"],
        ["xpath=//a[@name='action']", "xpath:attributes"],
        ["xpath=//div[@id='buy-confirm']/div/div[2]/a", "xpath:idRelative"],
        ["xpath=(//a[contains(@href, '#')])[91]", "xpath:href"],
        ["xpath=//div/div[2]/a", "xpath:position"]
      ],

Comment: I exported from selenium can't run the js code on console